Custom Staggered recycler view in android

I want to implement list of items.
I want to implement this, as one of the section in my application. What is the correct way of implementing this in Android, I need a starting point. Is this possible with a recycler view? Please share any library or github project if available.
val lManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
I tried below function to set view like this
private void setSpanValue() {
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
if (modelArrayList.size() == 1) {
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
} else if (modelArrayList.size() == 2) {
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
} else if (modelArrayList.size() == 3) {
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
} else if (modelArrayList.size() == 4) {
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
} else {
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
}
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, modelArrayList, checkEvenOrOdd(modelArrayList.size()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);}

Thank you in advance
